# Having loosely-coupled architecture without Biztalk ESB Toolkit

Tags: asynchronous, message-queue, biztalk, esb, biztalk2006r2

Is it possible to implement loosely-coupled architecture using BizTalk without utilizing BizTalk ESB Toolkit? Does BizTalk have this capability? The solution must be able receive and deliver messages in a synchronously in a queue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, BizTalk can do both synchronous and asynchronous patterns without the BizTalk ESB Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to help achieve this without resorting to the ESB toolkit is by implementing Canonical message schemas and a Canonical message pattern. This way you can help to insulate your solution from design changes in the external endpoints you are connecting to.

This is a useful article explaining the basics:

https://jamescorbould.wordpress.com/2013/08/25/thoughts-on-the-canonical-messaging-pattern/

You would need to exercise some caution with this pattern as it can become unmanageable if your solution continues to grow over time.